# Managing IIS .Net Authorization Rules with a powershell script

Tags: powershell, authorization, iis-7.5

I'd like to simply add some .Net Authorization rules in IIS (7.5 / win 2008 R2) using a powershell script with PS snap in. So far I was able to add some "allow" rules but not any deny ones.

Each time I try, it either does nothing or creates an "allow" rule, which seems odd, like if it was defaulting to allow all the time.

I tried with add-webconfigurationproperty and add-webconfiguration with no luck.

Maybe one of you has the correct command line to use?

For instance:

```
Add-WebConfiguration "/system.web/authorization" -value @{ElementTagName="Deny";users="*"} -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\Mysite"

Add-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.web/authorization" -Name "collection" -value @{ElementTagName='deny';users='test'} -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\Mysite"
```

will create 2 "allow" rules.

Same behavior if I remove `ElementTagName='deny'`. So weird. Like if the deny "mode" was to be accessed in some different way.

And for instance, if I go to IIS 8 and try to generate the script after adding a deny rule, the command line suggested is not working either.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question... but to achieve your goal, you can call `appcmd.exe` from powershell. See here an example to [add a deny rule](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772441(v=ws.10).aspx)...

Comment: Thanks Peter, indeed I already found a way to add a deny rule with the appcmd.exe but I consider this as a workaround. I would be surprised that it's not possible with the regular PS snap in.

Answer (score 1):

The command you should use to add a deny rule in your example is:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.web/authorization" -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\Mysite" -Name "." -value @{users='test'} -Type "deny"
```

This bothered me too & I also had trouble getting appcmd to do the same thing. I did get it working in the end & found that the `-Type` parameter was the important one. This wasn't all that clear to me from [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790572.aspx) which just says:

> The type of property to add.