# Deny Tag for Powershell Script Not Appearing

Tags: xml, powershell, permissions, web-config

I am new to writing scripts and am currently writing a script which will automate populating the contents of a web configuration file. However, every time I try to add a deny tag, it always populates it as an allow tag.

I am doing

```
Add-WebConfiguration '/system.web/authorization' -location 'Blue.aspx' -PSPath $path -value @{accessType='Deny';users='*'}
```

in my script, but the web config keeps populating as

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I want it to appear as

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I have also been using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/add-webconfiguration?view=windowsserver2019-ps) webpage for reference, but have not been able to find anything to help. I've tried a bunch of things to no avail.
Any thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30135330/696808 Looks like you might need to use `Add-WebConfigurationProperty`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Managing IIS .Net Authorization Rules with a powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135330/managing-iis-net-authorization-rules-with-a-powershell-script)