# IIS: add a Deny rule to .NET Authorization

Tags: powershell, iis-10, web-administration

Afternoon guys,

I'm working on going through some lockdowns for IIS, I need to add a Deny rule to .NET Authorizations for all anonymous users.
I have this, which partially works

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT' -filter "system.web/authorization" -name "." -value @{accessType='Deny';users='?'}
```

`?` is an alias for `All anonymous users`

It partially works, as in it creates the rule, but it's set as an `Allow Rule` even though I'm calling `Deny`.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to register as a `Deny Rule`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Managing IIS .Net Authorization Rules with a powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135330/managing-iis-net-authorization-rules-with-a-powershell-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer in the `Related` section off to the side. Don't know why this never popped up in my initial googling.
[Managing IIS .Net Authorization Rules with a powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135330/managing-iis-net-authorization-rules-with-a-powershell-script?rq=1)

My final code is

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT' -filter "system.web/authorization" -name "." -value @{users='?'} -Type 'deny'
```

Comment: I’ll try to set a reminder in a couple days when it’ll let me